# Adding multiple inputs by user dynamically

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm new to Django 2.0. I'm working on a project where I need users to input questions (from at least 1 to as much as they want). Like after adding one question they should have option if they want to add more in the same form field (like if I have a Textarea field it should be accepting multiple Textarea fields and can be displayed separately).

How can I do this, please let me know, thank you.

Comment: For backend validation you will probably need a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets). To dynamically add fields on the frontend you will need to do that with javascript. You can have a look at how the django admin handles that for adding related entities in model change views.

Answer (score 0):

For your backend model, you have two options:

- Have a single textarea field where users can type multiple questions. This is the simplest method for both frontend and backend, but will not be as clean.
- Have a dynamic number of text area fields.

To accomplish the second method, you would have two models:

1. One representing the list of questions. Lets call this `QuestionList` This would most likely have a ForeignKey field pointing to the `User`
2. Another representing a question. This would have a textarea field, as well as a ForeignKey to a `QuestionList`. You might also want to have an IntegerField representing the order in the list.

Note: Also instead of textarea fields, you could just use `CharField`s, but you will have to set a limit to the number of characters.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try implementing that

Comment: ooo i dont know about that, water malooOOoooonne. The `QuestionList` model is unnecessary, and can be overcome by just having the non-unique `User` ForeignKey on the `Question` model (effectively a 'one-to-many' relationship). This way theres one less table in you db. From there a FormSet can be constructed from the `Question` form to allow for multiple inputs

Comment: @stackPusher `QuestionList` model would be useful if you need to differentiate between different sets of question submissions from the same user. You could also accomplish this in your architecture with just a date submitted field, but if you needed to keep track of question order or other metadata about a set of questions, a separate table would be useful. W@termaloo000one out.